# Share Database through all pc users' account

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm developing a Windows Universal App, I need to share a database for all the users' account existing on pc.
Is it possible? What's the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Universal Apps the app data is stored in an app data store. When an app is installed, the system gives it its own **per-user** data stores for settings and files. So what you are asking is not possible using the native app data APIs. 
Also note:

> The system preserves the contents of these data stores when the user
>   installs an update to your app and removes the contents of these data
>   stores completely and cleanly when your app is uninstalled.

Source: [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx)